# Search Results always showing the same results

Tags: 2013, search, search-results

For some reason our search results are always the same. I'm trying to search only pages in our site collection.

In the search results webpart I have the result source set to **"Pages (System)".**

We have recently imported about 200 pages, but I did a full crawl. Any suggestions where the problem might be?

Comment: what you mean by same results? did you see the crawl logs if new pages are crawled.

Comment: Anything I enter into the search produces the same results page. The pages appear crawled in the latest crawl log.

Comment: Same for me in a SP foundation 2013

Comment: Same problem. By "same result" it returns the same files in the same order. It doesn't matter if my search is for "apples" or "candy". The results have nothing to do with the search. In fact it will return files that do not have the search term anywhere in them or their metadata.